# Should we turn Worldbuilding Stack Exchange into a Planet of Hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

November is rapidly turning into December, but we still have one more event to get through before we look ahead to 2017 . . . Winter Bash!

> The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically [hate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/268583#268583), it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - **it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!**
>
> **Overview**
>
> Most of you remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard that looks similar to this:
>
> [image: Winter Bash 2016 Leaderboard]
>
> As always, we’re coming up with new hat designs for this year’s fun!
>
> **The Details**
>
> The event will run from **19 December 2016** up to and including **08 January 2017**. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Worldbuilding participated in [Winter Bash 2014](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/609/627) and [Winter Bash 2015](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2815/627), and both seemed to be rousing successes.

Shall we take the plunge and turn Worldbuilding Stack Exchange into a [Planet of Hats](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetOfHats)?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Warning: TVTropes link!

Comment: Elaborate puns in answers are welcomed but by no means mandatory.

Comment: Whats the deal with the hats...

Comment: im just here to say: yay for hats!

Comment: Thanks @HDE226868 you should have *forewarned* me about that TV-Tropes link. I've been stuck there for about 19 days since I saw that link.

Comment: @Mooz In that case, you must be a time traveller. Care to share your secrets?

Comment: @randal'thor - be careful what you ask for; revealing the secret would probably mean more TV Tropes links....  :-p

Answer (score 40):

## Yes!

### Full speed ahead to *Planet of the Hats*!

Everyone loves hats - they promote lots more activity on the site during a time when there would usually be less activity.

There is no need to ruin the fun of everyone just because of a few weird outlying anti-hats who would hammer on the "I hate hats" button the moment they can. When they do this,the are warped out of hat land - ruining the fun only for themselves - instead of for everyone.

**Did I mention I like hats?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's almost here! *Counting every second*

Comment: and the excitement is through the roof!

Comment: Yeah, now only 49703 seconds left!

Answer (score 17):

I would be for hats.  Like X-27, I find that the hats do lead people towards more interesting questions and answers than they usually would.  It's a fun tool to help encourage people to leave their comfort zone.

The only concern I might have would be if the hats lead people to create poor quality questions or answers for the sole purpose of getting a hat in the "gotta catch 'em all" mindset.  In my opinion, this has not happened to a significant degree in past years, so I see no particular reason to avoid hats this year.

Comment: While true that the real hat fanatics *might sometimes go a bit overkill (but only a very very little bit) trying to get hats,* they generally are higher rep users who know better than to create garbage purely to farm hats.

Answer (score 11):

I would agree with X-27 if the button were not “I hate hats”. Hate is a strong concept and one of the precepts I try to live by is “do not hate”.

We need a button for

- I mildly dislike hats
- I’m not sufficiently interested to put up with it
- Don’t mess with my custom skins
- I like them, but I don’t want to take on anither distraction right now
- etc.

And all of that can be replaced with a purely **functional** label that does not get into motives at all, namely:

- I choose not to participate at this time.

Comment: This should be a feature request instead of an answer to this question because it doesn't address the OP's post.

Comment: There is a question on the main meta for this already.  Read the first answer to understand that it has nothing to do with hate.  Post your own answer or upvote other answers if the solution isn't sufficient to meet your needs. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270833/why-do-i-have-to-hate-hats

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a clue about this hats thing, but I'm in :)

Comment: That's the spirit

Answer (score -2):

## No, no hats.

*Note:* not necessarily my personal opinion.

Just to play devil's advocate, who doesn't want hats and why?

Comment: Can I downvote my own post plz?

Comment: Nope, but I can downvote for you if you wish. :)

Comment: I see why, and that "I hate hats" check box is very good option, useful? I almost hit this one, but I found one hat from 28 hats I like, and it is a good one)) The point is I upvote your answer, dark side is stronger!