# Do we participate in Winter Bash 2017?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I don't think Worldbuilding has missed any [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash) since the site's inception.

This year's [begins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303371/157730) in about a week. [Here's the countdown page](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/).

From [the answer to *Is there a simple page, “What is Winter Bash, and what's all this about hats”? Can we have one?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270511/157730)

> Winter Bash is a fun event, that starts every year in the middle of December, usually between [Hanukkah](http://www.calendarlabs.com/holidays/jewish/hanukkah.php)  and [Christmas](http://www.calendarlabs.com/holidays/us/christmas.php), and lasts until  the end of that year, for about 2 weeks. During this event, users are given "hats" for doing certain actions on the sites (hats are per site, like badges) and they can choose what "hat" to wear via their profile. That hat will be visible on top of their avatar for everyone to see. There is a spirit of competition inspired by having a global leaderboard, and a race to find the secret hats. When the event is over, the "hats" are all gone and can't be accessed anymore.

**Do we participate in 2017's Winter Bash? Please vote for *only one of* yes, no or indifferent,** as appropriate, by upvoting the appropriate answer. The final decision will be at the discretion of the moderators, but I promise that we will give due consideration to the community's vote. (I do not, however, promise anything about precisely *how much* consideration will be due. ;-))

I expect that there will be an "I hate hats" option, as usual, so that even if we do participate, those who don't want to see any hats can easily opt out on an individual basis.

Comment: I know that as things stand, folks will almost certainly vote to get hats this year, but I'd like to suggest for the sake of pedantry that we only count upvotes on the answers below, rather than net score.

Comment: @HDE226868 That is my definite intention, and has been all along. Otherwise people would get two votes, which seems potentially unfair.

Comment: With a net result of one vote for "no", three for "I don't care" and 14 for "yes", I'm calling this one a "yes".

Comment: I love hats.  I really should have kept a screenshot of each year...

Comment: @James It's not yet too late to start...

Comment: You didn't get hats? Why not?!! O.o And for that matter, I think it's a pretty silly initiative altogether. But that may be me.

Comment: @AliceD Not everything has to be dead serious. (Especially not on Worldbuilding.) And as I mentioned in the question, nothing prevents people from opting out if they don't want to deal with the silliness themselves.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Yes

Yes, let's participate in Winter Bash 2017.

Answer (score 5):

## I don't care

I really don't care whether or not we participate in Winter Bash 2017.

Comment: I would say "don’t care" if the wording for opting out did not say "I hate".

Comment: @JDługosz Well, you're certainly free to petition on [meta.se] for a different wording! It might not even be too late for this year's, as it would be a trivial change.

Comment: [two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270833/why-do-i-have-to-hate-hats/287795#287795) and they won't take it seriously or improve the UX for its own sake.

Comment: Here's my detailed post from a year ago: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4151

Answer (score 0):

## No

No, let's not participate in Winter Bash 2017.

Comment: Worldbuilding stack: no place for hat.